# Edit div content not working as intended React

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

react code

```js
class LoginIdCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      website: "",
      username: "",
      password: "",
      editMode: false,
    };
  }
  handleEdit = (fieldName, val) => {
    this.setState({
      [fieldName]: val,
    });
  };
  creatLoginCardItem() {
    const { logins } = this.props;
    const { editMode } = this.state;

    return logins.map((logins) => {
      return (
        <div className="card">
          <button onClick={() => this.handleEdit("editMode", true)}>
            edit
          </button>
          <p>{logins.website}</p>
          <p>{logins.username}</p>
          <p>{logins.password}</p>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { editMode } = this.state;
    return <>{editMode ? <input /> : this.creatLoginCardItem()}</>;
  }
}

export default LoginIdCard;
```

i.stack.imgur.com/CKXXb.png

The code snippet renders cards component as:
[web-app rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBRlf.png)

what i wanted is as i click the edit button the div content show be editable ,using a form input.
but as soon as i click the edit button, all the cards get replaced by a form.
i want to edit every card individually and save them to store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is not completely right. You have to set the state for every login card separately. It's not that difficult.

1. You need to create a new component LoginCardItem which contains all the state logic you use now. (e.g.: this.state.editMode, ...)
2. Change your current LoginIdCard to something like LoginCardOverview. To indicate this is an overview.
3. In LoginCardOverview you can loop over these logins.

return logins.map((login) => < LoginCardItem />)

This way every LoginCardItem will have it's own state.

Afterwards to change the input value: You will have to change the state of the input like this:

```
<input onChange={(e) => this.setState({name: e.target.value})} />
```

Comment: Ok. I did it...from a parent component (whrre it will be displayed) i passed the state as props to the loginCardItem. In parent component i map the state to render so that every cardItem had their own state.....by the way thank for the solution

Comment: Ok..  Another problem i faced is that when i clicked edit on a LoginCard....the input appears. The default value of the input field i set the value displayed originally.But the default value of the input does not change when i type someting over it